# Observation of User Defaults when changed in a Today Extension

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

I'm developing an radio player app which can play a couple of streams. This app has a today extension which shares some data over user defaults by using an App Group "com.myname.myapp". Now I would be informed whenever the user data are changing. Changes can come from the containing app and from the today extension. I added an observer in the container app to observe the `NSUserDefaultDidChangeNotification`.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)  
               name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];

- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // do the needful
}
```

The method is called whenever I make changes in the app itself but not when the same chages was made in the extension.

Do you have an idea whats is going wrong and what needs to be done to get a notification in the containing app when the extension changes user defaults? Unfortunately there is no direct way to tell the container app that the user was changing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get that notification in the app when the extension changes user defaults. It's not implemented, so there's nothing you can do to make that notification happen.

You can do one of the following:

- Observe `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiteNotification` in your app. Whenever the app becomes active, check user defaults to see if anything changed.
- Use [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) to set a flag so that your extension can tell your app that user defaults have changed.